# Puppet configuring iSCSI with multipath

Tags: puppet, rhel7, iscsi, multipath

I'm setting up some iSCSI storage (Lenovo) along with 3 physical servers running RHEL7.
Each server has 2 NICs for the main network (bonded) and 2 NICs for the iSCSI network. The Lenovo storage has 4 ports connected to 2 physical switches.  The iSCSI NICs in each server go to 1 port in each of the switches."

I'm using puppet to configure the iSCSI NICs and was wondering if I should create a bond for the connection to the storage?
Currently they're 2 separate NICs and the storage only reports seeing a single "host port" per server (I was maybe expecting to see two host ports per server?).  The storage describes the host port with the iscsi initiator name (as found in /etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi)

Alternatively is there a way you can get the iscsi service to go out on the 2nd NIC, so it registers a second host port with the storage?  Or am I worrying unnecessarily?

Thanks,

Rob.

Comment: This site is primarily for programming questions. You will get better answers if you post on one of the stack sites dedicated to server related questions. I would start with https://serverfault.com and see if they can help you.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of serverfault!